# Apple watch video playback

Tags: apple-watch

Can apple watch capable of video playback? I want to develop an app similar to vine for apple watch. So, user can consume video conveniently from the watch. Is it possible?

I have played with animating multiple images to create a video but it really is a bad approach. Anyone else comes up with any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update after WWDC 2015:**

Good news! Now it's possible!

Link to sample code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/WatchKitMoviePlayer/Introduction/Intro.html

Summary: 
Now there is a class (WKInterfaceMovie) that allows you to play videos on the watch :)

From the docs:

> A WKInterfaceMovie object lets you play back video and audio content
>   directly from your interface. A movie object displays a poster image
>   with a play button on top of it. When the user taps the play button,
>   WatchKit plays the movie in a modal interface.

Class Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMovie_class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the current APIs it might be difficult/impossible.
Still, the camera application on the apple watch is receiving a live stream coming from the camera of the iPhone at a quite good rate.
Most of the apple watch apps are not using only the publicly available APis but it shows that it should be feasible (not talking about the sound here...)

update: 
I had missed one feature, there IS an embedded video player with sound on the apple watch... have someone send you a short video has an iMessage and you are able to play it on the watch...

Comment: Thanks Xav, can you elaborate more about video player if you have more info.

Comment: I don't... I haven't seen this feature mentioned anywhere... all I know is that if the video is small enough (in my case few seconds) you can read it on the apple watch, if it's too big (I tried with 45s video) you get a message that the video is available on the iphone.